# Get Short Date Format/Style/Structure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Suppose my system date is 2014-02-10 & I have published my app on Internet Information System. Now Using DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString method I can get date like 2014-02-10, but how can get pattern/style/structure (e.g yyyy-MM-dd) for date? It should be irrespective of current culture.

IF I change date to 10-Feb-2014, then I should get dd-MMM-yyyy. 
What's the solution? Thanks in adv..

Comment: Think about it. Your VB code is executed on the server. Every client system, no matter where in the world, makes requests to your one server, where the VB code is executed. How can that server know what the default short date format is on any of those client machines? The VB code is executed to generate the HTML code that is then sent to the client. If the VB code is generating the date text then it's too late to do anything client-specific by the time the HTML code reaches the client.

Comment: You would need to execute some javascript code on the client to generate the text in order to provide a client-specific format. I don't know if or how javascript code can access the system date format but that is something that you can search for on the web.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney...I'm talking about Server date pattern & not for client PC format..I want Server machine date pattern like MM-dd-yyyy OR dd/MM/yyy Or something like this where code is running..

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. I thought you were saying that you wanted to format a date value but it seems that you're saying that you actually want the format string.  In that case, you need to use get an appropriate `DateTimeFormatInfo` object and get its `ShortDatePattern` property.  You can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` or `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat` to get that `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney..Can you explain by e.g. I have tried it..but getting wring pattern like MM/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy--MM-dd. I have stored value of DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() in string